# Pressure, force and mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, pressure

I need to know how much "weight" is needed to achieve a pressure.  Any explanation leads me to tangents that make it more confusing or overly simplified, and I do not trust my calculation.

I need to achieve 435 p.s.i.  I want to use common workout weights to apply force over an area of 0.0625 inches * 2.5 inches (0.15625 sq. in.).
From $p=F/a$, I think I need ~68 "pounds" (force); do I use 68 "pounds" of weights?

Comment: *Please forgive this question again...* If this means that you deleted and reposted, please don’t do that.

Comment: How are you going to apply this force over a strip only 1/16” wide?

Comment: You are supposed to explain what is confusing to you about your calculation. In general, check-my-calculation questions are off-topic, but conceptual-confusion questions are on-topic.

Comment: If you are confused about pounds of force vs. pounds of mass, you need to say so.

Answer (score 2):

67.96875 pounds of weight vertically supported evenly on an area of 0.15625 square inches would equal a pressure of 435 pounds per square inch, neglecting any additional atmospheric pressure.